# How to set the titleLabel.text of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, exc-bad-access

I would like to know how to do that properly because I am getting a Bad Access error.

In my app I have 81 `UIButtons` with an `IBAction` attached to all of them by Interface Builder, this `IBAction` should set the text of the button the user tapped on. I am trying to do that this way:

```
- (IBAction)changeTitle:(UIButton *)button {
    button.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myString];
}

-(IBAction)setMyString:(id)sender{
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text"];
}
```

However this comes into a Bad Access Error, how could I solve that?
Million Thanks!

error message: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
(lldb)

Comment: You need to update your question with the complete error message. Side note - do not use `stringWithFormat:`. You are not formatting anything. Just assign the string directly: `button.titleLabel.text = myString;`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have already tried to do this the way you are saying, however it keeps giving the same error. Any other option?

Comment: I didn't give you an answer. I told you that you need to update your question with the complete error message. The rest was simply a suggestion, not an attempt to fix the problem. Post the complete error or no one will be able to help.

Comment: okay I updated my answer, sorry for my bad interpretation, I thought you were answering

Comment: for the solution, you need to provide more details

Comment: sorry, I am not an expert, could you please tell me what could I add to help answer my question? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the syntax of the IBAction little different? Shouldn't it expect (id) sender parameter?

Comment: @NiravBhatt id implicitly casts to any object so if you know it's a button you can put UIButton * as the type

Comment: @yeker3 is button.titleLable non-nil?

Comment: @Lance the button is empty before this action runs. Is this the problem?

Comment: is this code running under ARC? If not your myString object will be released immediately and you try to assign a deallocated object in `changeTitle:`

Comment: ohh its true! I am not using ARC in this app, I did not remember, what should I do to keep it without having it auto-deallocated?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct! Thank you very much, it solved my error!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a memory management problem. You are not using a @property to set your instance variable. You are setting it manually so you have to manage the memory yourself.

```
-(IBAction)setMyString:(id)sender{
    [myString release]; // release old instance
    myString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text"] retain];
}
```

or even better, create a `@property` for your variable if you haven't done so already and set your variable by using the setter. Like this:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *string; // in your @interface
@synthesize string = myString;                // in your @implementation

-(IBAction)setMyString:(id)sender{
    self.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text"]; // setter will release old value, and retain new value
}

- (IBAction)changeTitle:(UIButton *)button {
    // you should not set the text of the titleLabel directly
    [button setTitle:self.string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally followed the second option!

Answer (score 5):

You should not try to set the label text directly, but use `UIButton setTitle:forState:`:

```
- (IBAction)changeTitle:(UIButton *)sender {
  [button setTitle:myString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The `label` property can be used to configure things like the font and other properties of the label, but some of them (color, shadow color and text) have to be set using the `UIButton` methods.

Comment: I corrected it, thanks for your comment. However, if this should fix my error, it does not for me